# matrix get min values of a matrix before max values occurred

Tags: matlab, max, min

I was trying to get the min values of a matrix before the max values of the matrix occurred. I have two matrices: matrix data and matrix a. Matrix a is a subset of matrix data and is composed of the max values of matrix data. I have the following code but obviously doing something wrong.

```
edit:
```

Matrix a are the max values of matrix data. I derived it from:

```
for x=1:size(data,1)
a(x)=max(data(x,:));
end
a=a'
clear x
```

matrix b code:

```
for x=1:size(data,1)
b(x)=min(data(x,(x<data==a)));
end
b=b'
clear x

matrix data   matrix a   matrix b
1  2   3  4      4        1
6  5   4  7      7        4
9  6  12  5     12        6
```

I need all the min values that occurred before to matrix a occurred in matrix data

Comment: How are you getting the `Max` data and is it correct?  Also could you elaborate on what the issue is?  Are you not getting the correct min values or is there an actual error in the code?

Comment: it's best to use other names for your variables than the names of builtin functions, even with different capitalization...

Comment: What is it that you want? can you give an example? eg. `data=[1 3 5 4 2 0]` --> `a=5` and then you want minimum of subset `[1 3 5]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple:

```
[a,idxmax] = max(data,[],2);
b = arrayfun(@(ii) min(data(ii,1:idxmax(ii))), 1:size(data,1));
```

which is the same as

```
b=NaN(1,size(data,1)); % preallocation!
for ii=1:size(data,1)
    b(ii) = min(data(ii,1:idxmax(ii)));
end
```

### Ignore maximum itself

If you want minimum of everything really before (and not including the maximum), it's possible that the maximum is the first number, and you try taking minimum of an empty matrix. Solution then is to use cell output, which can be empty:

```
b = arrayfun(@(ii) min(data(ii,1:idxmax(ii)-1)), 1:size(data,1),'uni',false);
```

### Replace empty cells with NaN

If you want to replace empty cells to Nan and then back to a matrix use this:

```
b(cellfun(@isempty,b))={NaN};
b=cell2mat(b);
```

or simply use the earlier version and replace `b(ii)` with `NaN` when it is equal to `a(ii)` same outcome:

```
b = arrayfun(@(ii) min(data(ii,1:idxmax(ii))), 1:size(data,1));
b(b'==a) = NaN
```

### Example:

```
data=magic(4)

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
```

outputs:

```
a' = 16    11    12    15

b =
    16     5     6     4
```

and

```
b =[1x0 double]    [5]    [6]    [4]
```

for the 2nd solution using cell output and ignoring the maximum itself also.

### And btw:

```
for x=1:size(data,1)
    a(x)=max(data(x,:));
end
a=a'
clear x
```

can be replaced with

```
a=max(data,[],2);
```

Comment: Definitely the shortest answer, by using matlabs built-in matrix for loop, `arrayfun` - nice one. I tried to go the full matrix path, but the code is less readable.

Comment: In regards to the max value occurring first, why does the output have to be a cell? Could it be replaced with NaN or 0?

Comment: using the for loop, yes, but you'll have to filter that out with an if/then/else thingie, using the arrayfun not directly, because it wants to spit things out with the same dimension; and `0x1 != 1x1` I'll edit to append this

Comment: @GuntherStruyf could you explain this index:                   [a,idxmax] = max(data,[],2);

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr. 6th line under description in [max documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/max.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but this is the only way I found so far of doing this kind of thing without a loop.

If loops are ok I would recommend Gunther Struyf answer as the most compact use of matlab's in-built array looping function, `arrayfun`.

Some of the transposition etc may be superfluous if you're wanting column mins instead of row...

```
[mx, imx] = max(data');
inds = repmat(1:size(data,2), [size(data,1),1]);
imx2 = repmat(imx', [1, size(data,2)]);
data2 = data;
data2(inds >= imx2) = inf;
min(data2');
```

NOTE: if data is not needed we can remove the additional `data2` variable, and reduce the line count.

So to demonstrate what this does, (and see if I understood the question correctly):

for input

```
>> data = [1,3,-1; 5,2,1]
```

I get minima:

```
>> min(data2')
ans = [1, inf]
```

I.e. it only found the min values before the max values for each row, and anything else was set to `inf`.

In words:

- For each row get index of maximum
- Generate matrix of column indices
- Use `repmat` to generate a matrix, same size as data where each row is index of maximum
- Set data to infinity where column index > max_index matrix
- find min as usual.

Comment: you can generate the index matrix `inds>=imx2` also with `bsxfun(@ge,1:size(data,1),imx')`

Comment: Isn't that yet another matlab loop function in disguise though?

Comment: yeah, but a quick one, quicker than repmat anyways. Also easier, because you don't have to preallocate and have indices flying around your code

Comment: @mutzmatron. thanks for the explanation on bottom. I'm a newbie to programming and don't understand how the program operates.

Comment: @mutzmatron, more on that here: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/ ;)